# Javascript: Get Coords from both clicking and dragging map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the below script in which a google map marker is placed when the map is clicked. It can then be dragged around for further precision. I would like to obtain the coordinates of the map pin in either case.

```
map.addListener('click', function (e) {
    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
});

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
    var position = latLng;
    console.log(position);
    while (markersArray.length) {
        markersArray.pop().setMap(null);
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        draggable: true,
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: "Select Your Location!"
    });
    map.panTo(latLng);

    markersArray.push(marker);

    map.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    var position = event.latLng;
    console.log(position);
    });
}
```

I get the click coords just fine, but I'm having trouble placing my `'dragend'` listener so that it picks up on the action. If it is placed inside the `placeMarkerAndPanTo` function, then it doesn't really 'listen' after the function is over. However, if I place it outside the function, then it has no idea what a `marker` is!

What is the simplest solution to this problem?

Comment: What do you want to do with the coordinates?

Comment: POST them to my database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drag marker and click to set at the same time in Google Maps API v3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069245/how-to-drag-marker-and-click-to-set-at-the-same-time-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the latitude and longitude of a draggable marker in a map (using javascript) into a form in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156233/is-it-possible-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-draggable-marker-in-a-map)

Comment: So you want to put them in some kind of a form?

Comment: Yeah, that is the ultimate goal. I want to pass them to a Django view.

Comment: Ouch.. low quality question? I can pull it down if its bothersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
markersArray.push(marker);

map.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
var position = event.latLng;
console.log(position);
});
```

should be:

```
markersArray.push(marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
var position = event.latLng;
console.log(position);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLu2eomv/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var markersArray = [];

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
  var position = latLng;
  console.log(position);
  while (markersArray.length) {
    markersArray.pop().setMap(null);
  }
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Select Your Location!"
  });
  map.panTo(latLng);

  markersArray.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
    var position = event.latLng;
    console.log(position);
  });
}

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving `var marker` outside of the function and just use

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Select Your Location!"
});
```

and then move the listener outside of the function.

Comment: For some reason, the listener doesn't respond when it is outside the function.