# Get lat and lng from draggable pushed marker (places search box)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Users have to choose their location on register form, im using places search box. 
 
For later application i need exact lat and lng, because of that i need a draggable marker. 
I provided a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/91FAbWgULMXmUSvcSkwt?p=preview)
Tried already various combinations witouth success like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragend', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("lng").value = event.latLng.lng();

    $('#lat').val(event.latLng.lat())  ;
    $('#lng').val(event.latLng.lng())  ;


});
```

The lat lng boxes won't get updated on drag. Listener get ignored.

Edit Additional info: "markers" is my variable for the created marker.
#lat, #lng are the id's for the hidden input fields.

**EDIT2:** I cleared up my whole code from plunker with necessary code only for this problem:

```
var inputradius = document.getElementById('myRange');
function initAutocomplete() {

  var CenterToCountry = {lat: 50.9725, lng: 11.4804};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: CenterToCountry,
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];

  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });

    markers = [];

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }


      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: place.name,
        draggable:true,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));


      var location = place.geometry.location;
      var lat = location.lat();
      var lng = location.lng();

      document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
      document.getElementById("lng").value = lng;

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
});


               google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragend', function () {
                var lat = markers.getPosition().lat();
                var lng = markers.getPosition().lng();


                $('#lat').val(lat);
                $('#lng').val(lng);
            });



}
```

Comment: What is `markers`?

Comment: @geocodezip hey, check plunker. It's the var for my marker. Im using markers instead of marker there ;D.

Comment: required information should be **in the question itself** (not a link to an external site)

Comment: @geocodezip sorry i tought it's logical. I will add now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lat, Lng doesn't update when I drag marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480496/lat-lng-doesnt-update-when-i-drag-marker)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Get Coords from both clicking and dragging map marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568520/javascript-get-coords-from-both-clicking-and-dragging-map-marker)

Comment: @geocodezip i edited post again now with whole code from plunker and clear up. No it's not the same because im using a pushed marker and places.

Comment: You can't add a "dragend" event listener to an array of markers, only to individual marker objects.  (`markers` doesn't have a `.getPosition` method, it is an array)

Comment: There is a syntax error in the posted code (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`).   Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip fixed, were missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can use places_changed event on your code,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
....
...
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

    $('#MAP_LAT').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
    $('#MAP_LNG').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
}
```

OR

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragend', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("lat").value = markers.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("lng").value = markers.getPosition().lng();
});
```

Note I didn't try it.

I have tested it, and code is below, I think you cant get marker variable correctly or I create the marker it and can handle it;

```
 if ($('#MAP_LAT').val() > 0 && $('#MAP_LNG').val() > 0) {
            markerNew = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: parseFloat($('#MAP_LAT').val()), lng: parseFloat($('#MAP_LNG').val())},//event.latLng,//
                map: map,
                icon: '../maps/GoogleMapsMarkers/original/red_MarkerH.png',
                title: 'My Marker',
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(markerNew, 'dragend', function () {
                var lat = markerNew.getPosition().lat();
                var lng = markerNew.getPosition().lng();
                $('#MAP_LAT').val(lat);
                $('#MAP_LNG').val(lng);
            });
        }
```

I found it and that is what I thought that is you can't use marker variable,
It is edited your plunker code
[screenshot your plunker code after edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR9mh.png)

and you can see whole plunker code for testing, place add this code after your function "places.forEach(function(place) {"

```
  console.log(markers);
  if(markers != null){
  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[0], 'dragend', function () {

  var lat = markers[0].getPosition().lat();
  var lng = markers[0].getPosition().lng();
  console.log(lat);
  });
  }
```

,Enjoy

Comment: Both are not working. I think the first will only triggered if i enter a new adress in the search box and the second the same problem like on my code, the listener get irgnored. @Ferhat BAŞ

Comment: Hi I have tested it and it works, if you created you marker then you can get position,

Comment: i added your code on my plunker preview. You can see there it won't work with places search box feature.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ru6bm could you please tell me what i did wrong ? oO @Ferhat BAŞ

Comment: You should show to which object is listened by addListener function you didnt give into function correct object(marker) your mistake is just this.